# AngularJS: POST request payload empty for ArrayBuffer

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-http

I tried to use POST to send some bytes using `ArrayBuffer`, but it seems that the request payload is always empty. Here's some code snippet:

```
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(10);
var dataView = new DataView(buffer);
dataView.setInt32(0, 0x1234ABCD);
var request = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'url',
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'},
  data: buffer,
  responseType: 'arraybuffer'
};
$http(request)
  .success(function(data, status, headers, config) { ... })
  .error(function(data, status, headers, config) { ... });
```

Comment: After some research, it turn out to be the issue of AngularJs. The buffer is not POSTed in the payload using AngularJs $http, I have to use XHR2 (which AngularJs wraps around) to POST the buffer directly, which is successful. More details refer to: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/#toc-send-string

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, to send ArrayBuffer, you need to use XHR2 directly (seems AngularJs doesn't support it). Here's some code of how to do it:

```
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(10);
var dataView = new DataView(buffer);
dataView.setInt32(0, 0x1234ABCD);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'url', true);
xhr.onload = function(e) {
  console.log('data received');
};
xhr.send(buffer);
```

More details about XHR2: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/#toc-send-string, hope this could help for someone who's also puzzled :)